# What is the name of this android view?

Tags: android, view

What is the name of this view and how can I make one just like it?

[image]

When a user click on it, it will make him choose between choices (image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Recyclerview with a Cardview or a Listview to achieve this design. Also you will need to create a standard layout like this and then call this layout in your Recyclerview adapter class. Google for tutorials on Recyclerview and you will come up with the best solution of code with a few modifications.

Comment: My pleasure...Happy Coding!